# interstitial ad vs native Ad

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, admob

I have developed an Ad and I am thinking about the monetarizing. I just saw AdMob and I tested the interstitial Ads in my App - works fine.

What I saw in a lot of apps is, that, when the AD is displayed (for example in games) you can play the displayed game in the Ad-Window -- I informed myself and I think that that are so called Native - Ads, am I right there?

I wanted to try it and implement it, but when I go to admob.com into my account and then to my app, all I can add is "Banner", "Interstitial" or "Video Reward" - No Native Apps listed there - which is kind of weird.

Can someone help me out?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Native Ads is not available to all AdMob users.

> Note: Native Ads Advanced is currently released to a limited set of
>   publishers. If you're interested in participating, reach out to your
>   account manager to discuss the possibility.

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native

You can try to contact AdMob team to ask them to activate Native Ads for your account.